# Can you write nested functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, nested

I am wondering if JavaScript supports writing a function within another function, or nested functions (I read it in a blog). Is this really possible?. In fact, I have used these but am unsure of this concept. I am really unclear on this -- please help!

Answer (score 234, accepted):

> Is this really possible.

Yes.

```js
function a(x) {    // <-- function
  function b(y) { // <-- inner function
    return x + y; // <-- use variables from outer scope
  }
  return b;       // <-- you can even return a function.
}
console.log(a(3)(4));
```

Comment: This method is called currying.

Comment: so are functions a type of object? sorry for necro

Comment: @CiY3 They are, [via MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions): "*In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, because they can have properties and methods just like any other object. What distinguishes them from other objects is that functions can be called. In brief, they are `Function` objects.*"

Answer (score 34):

The following is nasty, but serves to demonstrate how you can treat functions like any other kind of object.

```
var foo = function () { alert('default function'); }

function pickAFunction(a_or_b) {
    var funcs = {
        a: function () {
            alert('a');
        },
        b: function () {
            alert('b');
        }
    };
    foo = funcs[a_or_b];
}

foo();
pickAFunction('a');
foo();
pickAFunction('b');
foo();
```

Comment: Great example. I would add that it's important to note that functions defined inside other functions only exist in that functions scope (unless, of course, you assign a global function to it, as per this example).

Comment: Treat those functions like objects they are

Comment: why is that nasty exactly? Seems like it can be a useful alternative to a switch case

Answer (score 21):

Functions are first class objects that can be:

- Defined within your function
- Created just like any other variable or object at any point in your function
- Returned from your function (which may seem obvious after the two above, but still)

To build on the example given by Kenny:

```
   function a(x) {
      var w = function b(y) {
        return x + y;
      }
      return w;
   };

   var returnedFunction = a(3);
   alert(returnedFunction(2));
```

Would alert you with 5.

Comment: This method is called currying.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it is possible to write and call a function nested in another function.

Try this:

```
function A(){
   B(); //call should be B();
   function B(){

   }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Not only can you return a function which you have passed into another function as a variable, you can also use it for calculation inside but defining it outside. See this example:

```
    function calculate(a,b,fn) {
      var c = a * 3 + b + fn(a,b);
      return  c;
    }

    function sum(a,b) {
      return a+b;
    }

    function product(a,b) {
      return a*b;
    }

    document.write(calculate (10,20,sum)); //80
    document.write(calculate (10,20,product)); //250
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution with ES6 to other answers:

```js
const currying = (x) => (y) => x + y;
console.log(currying(5)(3));
```

will print to console: 8

Comment: A great read on this and a reason as to why it is called 'currying' can be found here https://javascript.info/currying-partials#currying-what-for

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculate(num1) {
   // arrow function
   return (num2) => num1 + num2;
}

// Invoke the function
console.log(calculate(4)(6));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this really possible?

It is very possible. You can do anything with functions in javascript since it is a first class function programming language.

```js
function add(x, y) {
  // we can define another function inside the add function to print our answer
  function print(ans) {
     console.log(ans)
  }
  const ans = x + y
  print(ans)
  return ans
}

add(1, 2)
```