# Is it possible to call the function locally defined in another function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, overriding

Is it possible to call the function locally defined in another function in JavaScript? I have a code pretty much like this:

```
var module = function () {
    function inner() {
        // Some code here
    }
    // Some code here
}

var originalModule = module;
var module = function () {
    originalModule();
    // inner() must be called here
}
```

So I'm overriding the original module implementation, but at some point in the new implementation I need to call inner() function. I cannot edit the original implementation. So far the only way I see is to copy inner() function from original and define it in the new one. Is there another way?

Comment: seems like very-very bad design. Why do you need to call it? If you need it outside the function, why declare it *inside* the function anyway?

Comment: No, you can't reach into a variable scope from outside. That would defeat the purpose of scope. You could have the original module *return* the function, or make it accessible in some other way, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `inner()` is defined inside of `module()` scope, you can't access it outside of this scope..

This pattern is used to implement **private** methods of `module()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually not a good practice, but you could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3212519/2483649):

```
  function a(x) {    // <-- function
      function b(y) { // <-- inner function
        return x + y; // <-- use variables from outer scope
      }
      return b;       // <-- you can even return a function.
   }
   a(3)(4);           // == 7.
```