# I want to call javascript function from function, but it don't work

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this error

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'sum' of undefined**

How it fixed?

```
function calculator(firstNumber) {
    var result = firstNumber;

    function sum() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= arguments.lenght; i++) {
        result += arguments[i];
    }

    return result;
    }

    function dif() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= arguments.lenght; i++) {
        result -= arguments[i];
    }

    return result;
    }
}

var myCalculator = calculator(10);
console.log (myCalculator.sum(2, 3));
console.log (myCalculator.dif(1, 2, 5));
```

I need to get:

15

2

Comment: Your calculator class does not return anything - that is the reason you get the error. Here is an example of the nested functions you are trying to emulate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212477/can-you-write-nested-functions-in-javascript

Comment: https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript

Comment: A lot wrong with this, starting with the typo: length

Comment: @KarthikRavindra,@epascarello Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `length` property of `arguments`, iterate `< arguments.length` and return an object with the two wanted function.

While you take result as variable, it keeps the value from the former calculation. The result is in the first part `15` and later `7`, instead of `2`.

```js
function calculator(firstNumber) {

    function sum() {
        for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            result += arguments[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    function dif() {
        for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            result -= arguments[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    var result = firstNumber;
    return { sum: sum, dif: dif };
}

var myCalculator = calculator(10);
console.log(myCalculator.sum(2, 3));
console.log(myCalculator.dif(1, 2, 5));
```

If you like to get always the result with `firstNumber`, you could initialize the result with `firstNumber`.

```js
function calculator(firstNumber) {

    function sum() {
        var result = firstNumber;
        for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            result += arguments[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    function dif() {
        var result = firstNumber;
        for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            result -= arguments[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    return { sum: sum, dif: dif };
}

var myCalculator = calculator(10);
console.log(myCalculator.sum(2, 3));
console.log(myCalculator.dif(1, 2, 5));
```

Comment: Nina Scholz Thank you!