# Function within another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, module

I was trying to call another function inside function iseven(n):

```
function iseven(n) {
    function remainder(n) {
        if (n%2==0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
console.log(iseven(4));
```

It returns undefined.

a right way to do this:

```
function a(x) {    // <-- function
  function b(y) { // <-- inner function
    return x + y; // <-- use variables from outer scope
  }
  return b;       // <-- you can even return a function.
}
console.log(a(3)(4));
```

[nested functions JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212477/can-you-write-nested-functions-in-javascript)

Comment: You have a function in a function. The outer one does not return anything. What did you want to do with 2 functions?

Comment: Because you have a function in a function

Comment: Remove `function remainder(n){` and one closing }

Comment: @nahu have you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Main function iseven() does not **return** anything. Based on your code it should return false. Here's the fix:

```
function iseven(n) { 
    function remainder(n) { 
        if (n%2==0) { 
            return true; 
        } 
        else { 
            return false; 
        } 
    }
    //iseven() should return something
    return false; 
}
console.log(iseven(4));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

`function iseven(n) { return n % 2 === 0; }`

Comment: if you expect it to return a `boolean`, i would do `function iseven(n) { return n % 2 === 0; }` but that's just being picky cause `0` and `1` that your functions returns are falsy and truthy values respectively

Comment: You are right @RicoKahler ! I will updated my answer

Comment: @nahu did my answer help you ?

Answer (score 2):

You want something more like this

```
function iseven(n)  { 
    if (n%2==0) { 
        return true; } 
    else { 
        return false; 
    } 
}

console.log(iseven(4));
```

And something a bit more succinct:

```
function isEven(n) {
   return n % 2 === 0;
}
```

Not quite sure why the original was structure that way..

Comment: i would prefer the [strict equality operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) but that's more of a style thing in the case of your example