# Nested function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form name="f1" method="GET">

    <form name="f1">
<input type="text" name="rd" id="rd">
<input type="text" name="fala" id="rd">
<button onclick="cal()"></button>





    </form>
```

How to use a nested function in javascript to print some output in HTML.

```
function abc() {
  var radius = document.f1.rd.value;
  document.write(radius)
}

function def() {
  var fala = document.f1.fala.value;
  document.write(fala)
}

function cal() {
  def()
  abc()
}
```

The nested functions should be called by single function and then will be used in button on click event

Comment: so should be  inside the "cal" function ?

Comment: `call()` doesn't have nested functions. It is just calling the functions `def()` and `abc()`. Are you asking how to get `call()` to execute onClick?

Comment: Okay . So how to use that call() function to print output of other two functions in HTML?

Comment: The functions assume that there's an existing form in the HTML with 2 inputs elements. Do you have those? If not the code won't work.

Comment: I have edited my post to add those

Comment: button onclick="cal();" but since it document.write this might won't work as expected. Start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: Possible duplicate and could be easy to find the answer with some more research. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3212477/10424104

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// Cache the elements and add a click listener to the button
const out = document.getElementById('out');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', cal, false);

function abc() {
  var radius = document.f1.rd.value;

  // Instead of using `document.write`
  // append the value to the output div
  out.innerHTML += radius + '<br />';
}

function def() {
  var fala = document.f1.fala.value;
  out.innerHTML += fala + '<br />'
}

function cal(e) {

  // Prevent the form from submitting to the server
  e.preventDefault();
  def();
  abc();
}
```

```html
<form name="f1">
  <label>RD</label><input name="rd" />
  <label>FALA</label><input name="fala" />
  <button>Cal!</button>
</form>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

- `button`s inside `form`s initiate [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type) by default, you can "neutralize" them via setting their `type` to `button`
- `document.write()` destroys the page, use an element for emitting results (like a `div`) and its `innerHTML`:

```js
function cal(){
  result.innerHTML=rd.value+", "+fala.value;
}
```

```html
<form name="f1" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="rd" id="rd"><br>
  <input type="text" name="fala" id="fala"><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="cal()">Click me!</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with console log and block default form submission.

```
<form name="f1">
    <input type="text" name="rd" id="rd0">
    <input type="text" name="fala" id="rd1">
    <button onclick="cal(event)">click</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function abc() {
  var radius = document.forms.f1.rd.value;
  console.log(radius);
}

function def() {
  var fala = document.forms.f1.fala.value;
  console.log(fala);
}

function cal(event) {
  def();
  abc();
  event.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```